# Creating a nested object from another controller gives error "couldn't find Object id = X" Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, simple-form

I would like the promoter to create a nested object (referree) in his Show.
Everything is set but it is - obviously not working. When submitting the form in Promoter / Show to create a Referee I have this error : "Couldn't find Referree with 'id'=1 "
What is wrong ? It is very important to create the form in this view and not another. How can I do ?

Thanks

My models :

```
class Promoter < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :referrees, dependent: :destroy
end

class Referree < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :promoter
end
```

First controller Promoters :

```
class PromotersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_promoter

  def show
    @referree = Referree.new
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @promoter = Promoter.new(promoter_params)
    @promoter.save
  end

  private

  def promoter_params
    params.require(:promoter).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email)
  end

  def find_promoter
    @promoter = Promoter.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Second controller Referrees  :

```
class ReferreesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_referree, only: [ :new, :create ]

  def new
    @referree = Referree.new
  end

  def show
    @referree = Referree.new
  end

  def create
    @referree = @promoter.referrees.build(referree_params)
    @referree.save
  end

  private

  def referree_params
    params.require(:referree).permit(:email)
  end

  def find_referree
    @referree = Referree.find(params[:promoter_id])
  end
end
```

Form in Promoter/Show view:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@promoter, @referree] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.submit "add a referree", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
before_action :find_referree, only: [ :new, :create ]
```

line from Referrees controller. Looks like you can't figure out what is does.